# What exactly is rigid body motion and symmetry in abstract algebra in terms of function?

Tags: abstract-algebra, symmetric-groups, isometry

My text book of abstract algebra states two definitions of rigid body motion and symmetry as following.

1. Rigid body motion : Rigid body motion of an object $X$ is a bijection from plane to plane s.t distance between $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ (which I think as new assigned value to object $X$) is same as distance between $x$ and $y$ .
   First of all I have doubt about how we actually represent an object say $X$ on plane what this set $X$ contains?(I think its contains ordered pair but for sake of simplicity we just label these ordered pair by say 1,2 etc.) .Second doubt is there any criteria set $X$ must follow in order to represent an object say a triangle . Lastly why rigid body motion is bijection(the reason I can think of is an object can be any where on the plane so bijection can't be for specific region if it is so what happens to the points other than point in set $X$ or purpose of  being bijective function is to just assign new values to object $X$ s.t if object after action/rigid body motion represented by another set say $Y$ then $f(X)=Y$ .
2. Symmetry : Symmetry of an object say $Y$ is bijection from plane to plane s.t $f(Y) = Y$.
   It basically says new assigned value to object Y must belongs to the set $Y$ . My doubt is why this function(symmetry) is bijection from plane to plane , as $f(Y)=Y$ implies function(symmetry) is bijection from  $Y$ to $Y$.(this is the definiton of permutation). So I must have misunderstood something.

Also give some reference on resourses to study this topic. As I may have interpreted everything wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure about your specific resource, but I think reflections are usually excluded from rigid motions.  That would be in addition to the isometry requirement you listed.   For 2, symmetries are usually defined to be invertible (and hence bijective) so that they form a group.

Comment: Which textbook are you referring to?

Comment: It is a  book of an open University ( IGNOU) with name Algebra and course code is BMTC 134

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any subset of the plane can be $X$ so if you want a triangle just pick your points and you've got one. A rigid body motion must both preserve distances and be bijective. The distances are what keeps them rigid and they are bijective because the transformations are invertible, since we can undo them.

Symmetries are a transformation that leaves some subset invariant, but it may move the points around. Say we have an empty square centered at the origin and we consider a quarter turn rotation symmetry. This will leave the square invariant as a set even though the position of the points has changed under the transformation. A similar situation occurs if you consider a reflection symmetry, where most of the points move but it's still a square afterwards. Again, these transformations are invertible, and so bijective. This will be useful because transformations with an identity and inverses will form an [group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_(mathematics)).

My first introduction to symmetries was in "Abstract Algebra" by Dummit and Foote.  Studying isometries and rigidity required some knowledge of metric spaces and linear algebra but the group theory I had first learned in this text was the most useful in studying these problems. Examples motivated by the wallpaper groups and crystallography helped me gain an intuition for the subject.

Comment: Your answer cleared many doubts but my main doubt is why both are bijection on whole plane instead of being bijection on set X(in case of symmetry)  . I want to know why we are then saying both are bijection on whole plane . I think purpose of being bijection on whole plane is if we move object in certain region only in that case domain of function(action) is set X and range is Y (newly assigned values) then f : X -> Y is also bijection. So I want to know bijection from plane to plane and bijection from X to Y are same function or different form each other.

Comment: @NikhilPathak they are functions on the whole plane because rigid motions apply to the whole plane. The functions on the plane are the transformations and what makes them symmetries or rigid motions is how they act on certain subsets. So it's the same function and we're examining properties of the function by looking at specific subsets.

Comment: can you please clarify that the transformation here means the transformations of objects in the plane right?

Comment: @NikhilPathak you can think of them as transformations of the objects in the plane, the entire plane itself, or simply as a bijective function. All three interpretations can be useful.